# How to populate listview in fragment?

Tags: android, listview, jdbc, navigation-drawer

I am working on an android application which implements Navigation drawer as its main menu then depending on the choices I do my operations. Now one of the task is to populate a listview from online mysql database host using jdbc. I am able to populate the listview in normal activity but the same code is not working in fragment. This is how my Fragment looks:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ListView listView ;
Connection conn=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
PreparedStatement st=null;

List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list, container, false);

    try 
    {
        initList();
    } catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] from = { "sender", "subject" ,"file_name"};
    int[] to = {R.id.sender,R.id.subject,R.id.file_name};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),list,R.layout.list_item,from,to);

    //ListView lv=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            //getListView();
    ListView lv= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                     int position, long id) {

                 String sender = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sender)).getText() .toString();
                 String subject = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject)).getText() .toString();
                 String fname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.file_name)).getText() .toString();

             }
         });




    return rootView;
}   



public void initList() throws SQLException 
{

    String username="sql428447";
    String pass="************";

    String sender,subject,file_name;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");         
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql4.freesqldatabase.com:3306/sql428447",username,pass);
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {

       String sql="select sender,subject,file_name from files";
       st=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

       rs=st.executeQuery();

       while(rs.next())
       {
           sender=rs.getString(1);
           subject=rs.getString(2);
           file_name=rs.getString(3);
           list.add(createRecord(sender, subject,file_name));
       }
   }
   catch(Exception z)
   {
       z.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally
   {
       st.close();
       rs.close();
   }


}
public HashMap<String, String> createRecord(String key, String name,String file_name) 
    {
        HashMap<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();
        record.put( "sender", key);
        record.put( "subject", name);
        record.put("file_name",file_name);
        return record;
    }
```

}

and I am calling this fragment from Navigation drawer select item like this:

```
        case 1:


         newFragment = new HomeFragment();
         transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
         transaction.addToBackStack(null);
         transaction.commit();

        break;
```

But at runtime in log its throwing exception on line initlist() and st.close() which I am not able to figure out. I guess my approach is almost correct which is discussed in most tutorials but I am not understanding fault in my code cause it is working in normal activity. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks 
This is the screenshot of exception
[image]

Comment: Please post more information about the exact Exception you are getting, including the type of Exception, the exception message and the precise location in the code where it is occurring.

Comment: I have included the screenshot of it now

Comment: use ListView lv= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list); instead of getActivity for anything you are implementing in Fragment

Comment: But that line isnt throwing exception

Comment: @Aashir its st.close()

Comment: St is null. Try changing "conn = DriverManager.getConnection(..)" to "this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...)"

Comment: @Aashir Not working same exception

Comment: Are you trying this on an emulator? Do you have Internet access?

Comment: Yes emulator with internet access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably benefit from using a `ListFragment`, I've seen many guides on the internet assume you are using one so it can get very confusing.

As for your current error, you're dereferencing `st` in the `finally` without verifying it's not null first. If `conn` throws an error you'll have this happen.

```
    try
    {

       String sql="select sender,subject,file_name from files";
       st=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

       rs=st.executeQuery();

       while(rs.next())
       {
           sender=rs.getString(1);
           subject=rs.getString(2);
           file_name=rs.getString(3);
           list.add(createRecord(sender, subject,file_name));
       }
   }
   catch(Exception z)
   {
       z.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally
   {
       if (st != null) {
           st.close();
           if (rs != null) {
               rs.close();
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: After ur suggested modification it is now throwing exception on lv.setadapter(adapter)

Comment: onCreateView is supposed to be generating the fragment's View and returning it for the Activity to use. You can't use findFragmentId against the activity there because you haven't given it the View yet.

Comment: Return the empty listview in `onCreateView` and by `onActivityCreated` it will have everything ready to use.

Comment: Sorry and thanks for the explanation but I am very new to android can you please give a little example code wise what you are trying to say

Comment: `ListView lv= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);` is where it is going bad. The activity does not get the listview until after onCreateView.

Answer (score 1):

You should have to use `ListView lv= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);` instead of `ListView lv= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);` ... `rootView` in place of `getActivity()`